# Automated emails via Microsoft Graph

Tags: python, graph, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Is it possible to send auto responses via Microsoft Graph from an O365 email address?

I am building a booking system using Python and Graph in which School's can book online educational sessions. Once they've finished the booking process I would like automated emails to be sent to them and the company. Is this possible via graph without a user being logged in or will I have to use something like SendGrid instead?

I know sending emails once signed in is simple enough but I just need automation from something such as noreply@companyname.com.

Thanks!

Comment: (1) Yes, you can send emails from an O365 email address by using Sendmail call. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http (2) You need to create Azure AD based workflow (say, daemon based app will work in your scenario). Here's the sample - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-python-daemon/ms-identity-python-webapp/. (3) In case of bulk emails and outside of Graph, yes you can consider options like sendgrid!!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, you can send emails from an O365 email address by using [Sendmail call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).
- You need to create Azure AD based workflow (say, daemon based app
  will work in your scenario). Here's the [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-python-daemon/ms-identity-python-webapp/)
- In case of
  bulk emails and outside of Graph, yes you can consider options like
  sendgrid!!